# Best option to custom Authentication using ASP .NET MVC (Cache, Cookie...)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am a bit lost using Authentication with MVC...

I´m looking for the best option to use in a big **E-Commerce** site, where the performance is top priority...

The two options I´m looking until now are :

- Create a *FormsAuthenticationTicket* and encrypt it into a **cookie**, like implemented here : [Cookie implementation](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/02/02/effectiveformsauth.html)
- **Cache** the Authentication data, like that :

  ```
  protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
      {
          if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
          {
              if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
              {
                  // Get Forms Identity From Current User
                  FormsIdentity id = FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                  // Create a custom Principal Instance and assign to Current User (with caching)
                  Customer principal = (Customer)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(id.Name);
                  if (principal == null)
                  {
                      // Create and populate your Principal object with the needed data and Roles.
                      principal = MyBusinessLayerSecurityClass.CreatePrincipal(id, id.Name);                            
                      HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(
                      id.Name,
                      principal,
                      null,
                      System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                      new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0),
                      System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default,
                      null);
                  }
                  HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

[Caching sample here](http://blog.codevelop.dk/post/2007/11/24/ASPNET-20-Forms-authentication-Keeping-it-customized-yet-simple.aspx)

What you guys think?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more *MVCish* way to achieve this is to write a custom [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) and perform this in an overriden [OnAuthorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter.onauthorization.aspx) method instead of using `Application_AuthenticateRequest`.

This being said I think that your implementation is quite good. As an alternative of storing the additional information into the cache you could store it in the `userData` part of the authentication ticket if this information is not very large of course. Both approaches are viable. If you decide to go with caching I would recommend you offloading it to dedicated cache servers instead of storing it in the memory of the web servers.